# Fastest way to find 5%ile from 2D numpy array?

Tags: performance, sorting, numpy, percentile, partial-sort

I know that there is `numpy.percentile(myArray,5)`, but I understand that behind the scenes this will first do a complete sort of the array, which is inefficient if I only need the smallest 5% of values sorted. I also have read that the heap-sorting approach is good for this partial sorting problem, but I can't seem to find an implementation that works for 2D numpy arrays.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import numpy, time
#create some fake data (like an opencv greyscale image)
a = numpy.random.randint(0,256,640*480).reshape([640,480]).astype('uint8')
#time the numpy.percentile approach
start = time.time() ; temp = numpy.percentile(a,5) ; print time.time()-start
```

That takes about 15ms on my system (too slow for my real-time application).

Trying heapq:

```
import heapq
start = time.time() ; temp = heapq.nsmallest(int(640*480*.05),a.flatten())[-1] ; print time.time()-start
```

Takes 300ms on my system; so much for my hope that heapq could speed things up!

Comment: How big is the array, and how precise do you need to be? You could use a random subset of it and get roughly the same answer. If you just chose 200 numbers, sorted them, and picked the 10th one, you'd have a pretty good answer.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Though it doesn't actually answer the question as stated (presumably why you submitted it as a comment), this does help in the interim, so thanks!

Comment: To be more precise, if you randomly choose 201 numbers, sort them, and then choose the 11th one, that value would have 10 numbers less than or equal to it, and 190 numbers greater than or equal to it, so it would be a 5th percentile.